# Is there a short method to counting for large cases?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have an $N\times N$ grid forming $N^2$ squares , we need to count total number of $4$ squares we can choose such that out of $6$ pairs possible $3$ pairs have one vertex in common and other three not any.

( I was easily able to solve it for smaller values like $N= 2,3,4$ by counting) but how about $N= 5,6,7?$

Comment: Exactly one vertex in common, or at least one vertex in common?

Comment: Exactly one vertex common for only 3 pairs , other 3 no vertex at all common.

Comment: What did you get for $N=2,3,4?$

Comment: The best thing you can do is list the configurations. For example, $(m,n),(m+1,n+1),(m+2,n+2),(m+3,n+3)$ is one configuration. How many of these are there?

Comment: For N= 2 ,0 combination , N= 3,4 combinations ,N= 4 , 46 combinations i got , i was doing that only checking for every configuration, i thought there might be some invariance which can make it easy to count all cases together rather than making cases as such for N = 4  , cases were 5

Comment: If you know how many ways there are for a $3\times3$ and a $4\times4$, perhaps you can think about the number of $3\times3$ and $4\times$ sub-squares there are on the board.  It seems to me that every such configuration will fit in one of these sub-squares, and that a configuration that can be covered by a $3\times3$ can be so covered in only one way.  (If I'm wrong about this, you'll have to adjust for double-counting.)  For the ones that require a $4\times4$, I would guess that double-counting will occur.

Comment: I haven't written anything down, so I may well be wrong, but if you've done the $n=3$ and $n=4$ cases, you should be able to check.  Or perhaps we should consider $2\times4$ and $3\times4$ rectangles as well.

Comment: Have you covered graphs yet in class? A graph with four nodes and three edges is either a tree, or a triangle and a disconnected point. But there is no way to get three squares each pair of which has exactly one vertex in common. So the underlying graphs are trees. This should help you classify each type of shape for these configurations.

Comment: The idea of considering the 4*2,4*3,3*3,4*4 grids in N*N ,N>=4 for counting gave me how to solve it , thanks .

Comment: I dont know about graph theory but still i can realize what u meant by that @Thomas Andrews thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any such configuration, consider the smallest sub-grid that contains it.  By a sub-grid, I mean a rectangle composed of cells of the original grid, and we can take "smallest" to be in terms of area.  There is a unique smallest sub-grid containing any configuration.  (If there were $2$, the configuration would be contained in their intersection, which has a smaller area.)

Now I count $2$ configurations requiring a $2\times4$ sub-grid, $4$ requiring a $3\times3$ sub-grid, $4$ requiring $3\times4$ and $2$ requiring a $4\times4$ , and none requiring a larger sub-grid.

To count the configurations in a $4\times4$ grid, note that the are three $2\times4$ sub-grids, and of course three $4\times2$ sub-grids, four $3\times$ sub-grids, tow $3\times4$ sub-grids (and two $\times3$ sub-grids,) and one $4\times 4$ sub-grid.  This gives
$$
3\cdot2\cdot2+4\cdot4+4\cdot2\cdot2+1\cdot2=46
$$
admissible configurations, in agreement with your count.

I leave it to you to develop the general formula.

Comment: Yeah i now got a idea on how to generalize it thanks